# Nested sepBy1 with same delimiter

Tags: haskell, parsec

```
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell

import           Control.Applicative           ((<|>))
import           Text.Parsec.Char
import           Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec hiding (spaces, (<|>))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ parse p "" "a\nb\n\nc\nd" where
  p  = sepBy1 (try pp) newline
  pp = sepBy1 l newline
  l  = many1 letter
```

I am trying to parse this:

```
a
b

c
d
```

to this: `[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]`. I tried fiddling with `try` but it doesn't seem to be working.

It is probably something quite basic, please try to explain what is going on in your answer (I am beginner in Haskell and Parsec).

Edit: Forgot to add an error message.

```
Left (line 3, column 1):
unexpected "\n"
expecting letter
```

Comment: What is not working? You get a compiler error? Wrong output?? Please be specific about what your problem is.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, forgot to add an error message. I have added it to the question.

Comment: There are two newlines separating each segment of letters

Comment: @Euge Oh, you are right, overlooked that. But even if I use `p  = sepBy1 (try pp) (newline >> newline)` it still doesn't work ._. (same error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the implementation of sepBy1, because the error appears even for  `parse pp "" "a\nb\n"`. While we expect this to return `Right ["a","b"]`, it throws the same `expected \n` error.

So, it looks like `sepBy1` works as expected, except in the case where the string to parse ends with the separator. This seems to be harmless, because there's another parser combinator for that case. But now that we want two nested `sepBy1`s with the same separator, that's a problem.

The only solution I found is to write your own backtracking `sepBy1`, and use it in the inner case.

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ parse p "" "a\nb\n\nc\nd"
  where  pp = mySepBy1 l newline
         l  = many1 letter
         p  = sepBy1 pp (newline >> newline)

mySepBy1 parser separator = do
  x <- parser
  xs <- many (try $ separator >> parser)
  return (x:xs)
```